# Having some problems with my batch code. Can't find out why it's throwing an error because of a parentheses

Tags: batch-file, optimization, compiler-errors, parentheses

Grab the code for yourself and check it out, every time it is able to ask me for the start time, and then if it's am or pm, but as soon as I click enter for am/pm, it closes straight away, I took a screenshot while it closed and it said that `( was unexpected here`. If someone can help out that would be great. (Also, if anyone has trimming and optimisation tips, that would be awesome as well. Thanks)

```
@echo off

:questions
set am=am
set pm=pm
set y=y
set n=n
:1
cls
set /p start=[Shutdown time (The hour of shutdown, do not add minutes):]
set /p 1ampm=[am/pm:]

if %1ampm% EQU %am% (
    PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
    goto :2
) else (
    if !1ampm! EQU %pm% (
        PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
        set realstart=%start%+12
        goto :2
    ) else (
        cls
        echo you did not enter whether or not the start time is am or pm
        goto :1
    )
)
:2
cls
set /p end=[Enter the time you want the computer to be available again for use(The hour of shutdown, do not add minutes):]
set /p 2ampm=[am/pm:]

if %2ampm% EQU %am% (
    PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
    goto :loading
) else (
    if !2ampm! EQU %pm% (
        PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
        set realend=%end%+12
        goto :loading
    ) else (
        cls
        echo you did not enter whether or not the start time is am or pm
        goto :2
    )
)
:loading
cls
echo Loading....
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL
cls
set /p yesno=[The time you selected the computer to remain off is from %start% - %end% , is this correct, y/n:]
cls
if %yesno% EQU %y% (
    PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
    goto :Begining
) else (
    if %yesno% EQU %n% (
        PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
        goto :questions
    ) else (
        goto :questions
    )
)
:Begining
set mytime=%time:~0,2%

:Start
if %mytime% GEQ %realstart% (
    cls
    echo time has expired, time to go to bed.
    shutdown -s -f -t 60 -c "Your computer is about to be shut down in 1 minute"
) else (
    if %mytime% LEQ %realend% (
        echo time has expired, time to go to bed.
        shutdown -s -f -t 60 -c "Your computer is about to be shut down in 1 minute"
    ) else (
        cls
        echo This program is Opperating correctly
        PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 600000 >NUL
        goto :Start
    )
)
```

Comment: I am quite sure the problem is caused by the variable name `%1ampm%`, because `%1` is interpreted as the first argument passed to the batch file (see `call /?` for details about that); so chage the name to something that does not start with a number!

Comment: @aschipfl 52 seconds before I submitted, I guess great minds *do* think alike

Comment: Ah, damn, you beated me, I was just preparing the related answer... ;-) +1 anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in these lines:

```
set /p 1ampm=[am/pm:]
```

and

```
if %1ampm% EQU %am% (
```

The problem is the variable name. Batch can get arguments when calling a batch file, for instance `%1` or `%2`. This causes batch to see it as if `%1 ampm % EQU % am%`, however it has no arguments, so %1 is empty. After that it sees the first percentage sign, sees it  has no numbers after it, and treats it as the start of a variable called `% EQU %`, which is empty too. then, it removes the last percentage sign, leaving you with just `ampmam (` as the line. that is what throws the error.

So, to solve the error, simply start variables with something other than numbers.

Comment: delayed expansion also helps in such cases

Comment: @npocmaka you're right, however it still would be best practice to not start variables with numbers.